# Android Eclipse - How to center a button

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't make the `Buttons` center on the screen. The text on top is in center, but the next 2 `Buttons` are lying left and vertical center. How I can make them horizontal center as well? T

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnTotal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnTotal"/>
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtract one"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"/>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use relative layout.

Comment: Don't know why the code not shown out before.

Comment: You needed a line break between the text and the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which layout you're using. It is much easier to center a button using a RelativeLayout.

Here is an example of how a button can be centered using a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Mainpage">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_round" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can probably tell, the two lines of code that are centering the Button in the middle `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`